# Panel data handling in R

Tags: r, panel

I am really new in r and stackoverflow. Apologies in advance for this novice question.

I have a panel data set like the following table.

## ID--------Choice

1  -------- 5
1  -------- 1
1  -------- 2
1  -------- 5
2  -------- 1
2  -------- 1
2  -------- 5
2  -------- 1
3  -------- 1
3  -------- 3
3  -------- 1
3  -------- 2

I want to add another column like the following table when choice is 1. This is basically, sequencing the choice 1 within ID.

## ID--------Choice----BUS

1  -------- 5--------0
1  -------- 1--------1
1  -------- 2--------0
1  -------- 5--------0
2  -------- 1--------1
2  -------- 1--------2
2  -------- 5--------0
2  -------- 1--------3
3  -------- 1--------1
3  -------- 3--------0
3  -------- 1--------2
3  -------- 2--------1

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Pasha

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(BUS = ifelse(Choice == 1, cumsum(Choice == 1), 0))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID Choice   BUS
   <int>  <int> <dbl>
 1     1      5     0
 2     1      1     1
 3     1      2     0
 4     1      5     0
 5     2      1     1
 6     2      1     2
 7     2      5     0
 8     2      1     3
 9     3      1     1
10     3      3     0
11     3      1     2
12     3      2     0
```